# Ruby on Rails: Rendering json and layout together in an action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have an action that looks like this

```
def asset_map_fullscreen
      @config_items = @config_item.ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:secondary, :relationship])
      @config_items_associated = @config_item.reverse_ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:primary, :relationship])

      @next_level = process_relationship
      render :json => @next_level :layout=>false
  end
```

My purpose is to return a json data and also want to execute `:layout=>false` . Is there a way to achieve this with a single action ?

When I give `render :json => @next_level` alone , it's just rendering the json data in my page and nothing else.

I have a `asset_map_fullscreen.html.erb` file also. I want to render this file along with the sending a json response ( i need the json data to do some actions ).

Comment: It is unclear what are trying to achieve. `render` will render _either_ json response _or_ html. Do you want it to reflect the request type, e.g. when `xhr` then render json, otherwise render html? Or what?

Comment: Is there any error on current implementation?

Comment: This is my first time with rails , The scenario is like this. When i click on a link , a new action with a different layout will be rendered. For the first time alone i need that action to return a json data. Just want to know whether this is possible.

Comment: Do you want to display json within the asset_map_fullscreen.html.erb page? You cannot render both json and html at the same time (or any other combination for that matter)

Comment: @SoorajChandran check my updates, also next time clarify your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to render this file along with the sending a json response (I need the json data to do some actions.)

**TL;DR:** This is not possible due to http proto specs. One should do two separate requests.

The easiest way to accomplish your task is to render `html` (via `erb` or whatever,) then call *another* controller action (say, `asset_map_fullscreen_json`) using javascript/AJAX from the page rendered. On the other hand, you might use the same endpoint (while still separating main request and subsequent AJAX call):

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render layout: false } # or whatever to simply render html
   format.json { render json: @next_level.to_json }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to render only json than do it like this.

```
render :json => @next_level
```

If you want to render some html file do it like

```
render partial: 'asset_map_fullscreen'
```

and you wan to render both. This is not possible . The possible solution is

```
render partial: 'asset_map_fullscreen', data: @next_level
```

With this you can access variable in partial. You should do required calculation in partial.

There is another possibility that you create js file with action name and in that file do your checks. For this have a look at @7urkm3n answer

And the last solution is save these in hidden filed somewhere in the partial and then extract it from the html with javascript.

Comment: I have edited the question. I think it was lacking clarity

Comment: “You should do required calculation in partial.”—one should _never_ do _any_ calculations in views.

Comment: Its a js request. The result would be in some js file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want to render the `asset_map_fullscreen.html.erb` template but also need the json in that page (for some reason, like manipulating the data or whatever) you can just render the template and pass the json as an instance variable that you can use within the view file:

```
def asset_map_fullscreen
  @config_items = @config_item.ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:secondary, :relationship])
  @config_items_associated = @config_item.reverse_ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:primary, :relationship])

  @next_level = process_relationship
  @next_level_json = process_relationship.to_json
  render :asset_map_fullscreen
end
```

Then within the view code you can reference `@next_level_json` so you can keep `@next_level` as regular object. Not sure where `process_relationship` is coming from though (method on your controller?)

Do understand that you can only return to the browser one type of `Content-Type` which could be json, html, xml, binary, whatever you want, but just one thing at a time. If you need to display an html page and render it to the browser and yet pass around json then you just would render the template as html (as pointed above) and save your json data in an instance variable to use within the view. You simply can't return html and json (as in an xhr/ajax request) on the same response.

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render :layout => false, :data => @next_level.to_json }
end
```

or simple

```
render json: @next_level
```

Hopefully this will work for you

Comment: I have edited the question. I think it was lacking clarity

Comment: if you want to do something like that then you can create a new layout and use it or you can use this gem https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma in render. Mostly if rendering JSON, then you do not need `layout`, Its preferable only HTML.

**UPDATED**

When calling like this, you getting objects, all is you have to append it in that page later where you want.

> JS file:

create `asset_map_fullscreen.js.erb` file, In page add this one.

```
console.log('yeah worked to test only');
console.log(<%= j render @next_level %>);
```

> Controller:

```
def asset_map_fullscreen
      @config_items = @config_item.ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:secondary, :relationship])
      @config_items_associated = @config_item.reverse_ci_relationships.find(:all, include: [:primary, :relationship])

      @next_level = process_relationship
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {}
      end
  end
```

Now you need to add `remote: true` to your button or form_for, no matter what.

If you post it i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: `render :json => @next_level` works

Comment: I have edited the question. I think it was lacking clarity