# Template is missing for request formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error:

`StaticController#home is missing a template for request formats: text/html`

This is my controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

    def home
        # render json: {status: "is working"}
    end

end
```

When I uncomment the comment above, it renders that.
my views/static/home.html.erb view:

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'index' %>`

and my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions, only: [:create]
  resources :signup, only: [:create]
  delete :logout, to: 'sessions#logout'
  get :logged_in, to: 'sessions#logged_in'

  root to: "static#home"

  # get '*path', to: "static#home", via: :all
end
```

Comment: Try `@status = "is working"`. And you'll be able to access this variable in your partial.
What you're doing right now with `render json:` is trying to render a "json object". But when you're requesting it with your browser, you're asking for an html page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419544/ruby-on-rails-rendering-json-and-layout-together-in-an-action for example.

Comment: And here is the official documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: add in the routes resources :static and inside the static folder add home.html.erb